# Symbloc expression vector into matrix form

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have a symbolic expression vector like: `[-2*y+x-4,-5*y+x+13]`.
How can I decompose it into two variables, say `A = [-2 -5; 1 1]` and `b = [-4;13]`?

But this should be done dynamically for n number of variables and m entries of the row vector.

Comment: Check out the `coeffs` function. You'll need to apply it to each element of your polynomial vector. Then it just remains to rearrange the outputs to get your `A` and `b`.

Comment: @horchler exactly what I need! Thanks

Comment: the output is almost what I need. It is still a symbolic vector though, is it possible to change that vector into a simple constants vector?

Comment: Use `double` to convert.